# Segue not being performed in a conditional statement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I'm currently trying to get a conditional statement to use `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`. Currently, I receive no error but the segue is not performed. The project is using Facebooks SDK so `loginButton()` is called when the user logs in (this part works, the console prints "user is logged in" which confirms that SDK if functioning properly)

The identifier is spelled correctly within the storyboard

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: view.frame.maxY - 50, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 32)
        view.addSubview(loginButton)

        loginButton.delegate = self
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!)
    {
        if error != nil
        {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        else
        {
            print("user is logged in")
        }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "postToView", sender: self)

    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!)
    {
        print("logged out")
    }

}
```

This is what the storyboard looks like
[image: Storyboard]

How can I get it to perform the segue once the conditional is true?

Comment: Add a print statement - first line - in loginButton(). You don't show how loginButton() is called. I suspect that is the problem.

Comment: @PriceRingo forgot to mention, this is using the Facebook SDK so it called loginButton once the user is logged in

Comment: Can you print your storyboard?

Comment: @ClaudioCastro Went ahead and posted a picture of the storyboard

Comment: Your loginButton is getting deallocated.  Save a reference to it in your view controller.

Comment: @Calimari328 Not sure if that's the problem. The if else statement is being called and it's going through the conditions/running the print statement

Comment: @hpcsolo ok, is your LoginViewController inside a UiNavigationController?  I can not verify this based on your image.

Comment: @Calimari328 No, the `LoginViewController` is the initial ViewController which is then supposed to direct to the `TabBarViewController` after a user has been authenticated

Comment: You are trying to perform a push segue.  LoginViewController MUST be inside UINavigationController in order for a push segue to work.

Comment: @Calimari328 I see! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Also if you don’t want to use UINavigationController then change the segue “kind” to the modal one.  you currently have it set to “show e.g. push”.

Comment: @Calimari328 Yup, that worked! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Replace the call to segue in loginButton() with this.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    [unowned self] in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("postToView", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: There is no `dispatch_async` in modern Swift.

Comment: Put a print statement before and after the call to segue so that we know whether it made it that far.

Comment: @PriceRingo Print statements post before and after